# Openlayers map goes blank when switch tabs

Tags: openlayers-3

I have an openlayers 3 map, which is using an openstreetmap basemap. Everything is working fine, but if I have other tabs open, and I switch to another tab for a minute, and they switch back to the openlayers tab, I see the map for a split second, and then the whole map turns white.  If I click off the tab to another tab, and then go back to the openlayers map tab, the map reappears again.  Has anyone else experienced this, or have any idea what might be going on?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen the map go white but never put it together with the tabs. TY, time to try to reproduce.

Comment: An additional note, resizing the map also causes the tiles to redraw.

Comment: sorry, I'm unable to reproduce either issue

Comment: The second comment isn't an issue, just saying the map is blank until I resize the screen.

Comment: can you update your question w/ the code you're using to create the map?

Comment: I'm thinking this is a chrome bug.  The issue doesn't exist on other browsers.  Chrome seems to be suspending things on inactive tabs or something.